# Intellij does not pick lambok while running the application

Tags: maven, pom.xml, lombok, maven-compiler-plugin, intellij-lombok-plugin

This is what my build looks like

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>build-image</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <skip>true</skip>
                <image>
                    <name>restaurant-image</name>
                </image>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                    </exclude>
                </excludes>
                <layers>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </layers>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                        <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
                    </path>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                    </path>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
                        <version>${org.projectlombok.lombok-mapstruct-binding.version}</version>
                    </path>
                </annotationProcessorPaths>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

These are the warnings I get when I run the pom, build is successful though

```
WARNING: A Java agent has been loaded dynamically (C:\Users\mazin\.m2\repository\net\bytebuddy\byte-buddy-agent\1.14.12\byte-buddy-agent-1.14.12.jar)
WARNING: If a serviceability tool is in use, please run with -XX:+EnableDynamicAgentLoading to hide this warning
WARNING: If a serviceability tool is not in use, please run with -Djdk.instrument.traceUsage for more information
WARNING: Dynamic loading of agents will be disallowed by default in a future release
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Sharing is only supported for boot loader classes because bootstrap classpath has been appended

[WARNING] Overwriting artifact's file from C:\Users\mazin\Downloads\demo\restaurant\target\restaurant-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar to C:\Users\mazin\Downloads\demo\restaurant\target\classes
```

The build is successful but when I try to run my application, IntelliJ throws errors related lombok setters like this and I do not see any compilation issues on my project structure in Intellij

```
java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method setId(java.lang.String)
```

Comment: Added lombok as dependency ? https://projectlombok.org/setup/maven

Comment: Yes. Otherwise, imports itself will show a compilation issue.

Comment: Lombok need annotations active

Comment: I have tried that and it didn't work.